# ¿Qué significa public static synchronized en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de realizar en java una clase que me calcule la complejidad de distintos algoritmos. Estos algoritmos se los paso por otras clases y en una de ellas que tengo como ejemplo es la siguiente:

```
public class Prueba2N {

    public static synchronized int f(int x, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (x / (f(x, n - 1))) + (f(x, n - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

La verdad es que tengo curiosidad por saber qué significa.

Comment: Que entendiste y que de lo que significa cada uno de esos terminos?

Comment: Es que no me lo han explicado, nos lo dan hecho y quería saber que sig. por curiosidad

Comment: Claro, lo entiendo, ahora, lo buscate en la guia de java, leiste lo que dice alli y tenes alguna duda respecto a eso que leiste?

Comment: Explicación clara y sencilla [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21812453/5587982).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Public** significa que el acceso a la funcion esta permitido para otras clases.

**static** significa que es una función estatica es decir que esta cargada desde el principio, por lo cual no necesitas crear un objeto para invocarla.

**synchronized** significa que es una función que soporta el manejo de concurrencia en hilos. Es decir, al entrar a un bloque sincronizado se genera un bloqueo, para que ese código se ejecute solo y no haya concurrencia de otros procesos, y al salir el de la sección se libera ese bloque de código, permitiendo acceder a los otros procesos a ese código.